# Angular template not update inside view, but $scope is update

Tags: angularjs

when thi is my main html file:

```
<html ng-app="app">
...
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
{{myData}}
<button ng-click="update()">Update</button>
<ng-view><ng-view>
</body>
```

this is my view:

```
<button ng-click="update()">Update</button>
```

and js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', { templateUrl: 'tpl.html', controller: 'MainCtrl' })
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function () {
    $scope.update = function () {
        $scope.myData = 'upd';
console.log($scope.myData)
}
}]);
```

I see my button inside view and haven't error inside console. When I click it, i see in console 'upd', but inside page its not update. When I write this:

```
$scope.update = function () {
  $scope.$apply(function(){
    $scope.myData = 'upd';
  })
}
```

I have an error "already in progress". How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are loading MainCtrl twice. You should put once, or in HTML like you did in `<body>`, or in routes `.when('/', { templateUrl: 'tpl.html', controller: 'MainCtrl' })`. Choose one.

Actually, your code is a little bit strange. You are writing `<button>` twice, in the main HTML and in the view? You should have just one, like this:

HTML:

```
<html ng-app="app">
...
<body>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

TPL.HTML:

```
{{myData}}
<button ng-click="update()">Update</button>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']).config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', { templateUrl: 'tpl.html', controller: 'MainCtrl' })
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function () {
    $scope.update = function () {
        $scope.myData = 'upd';
    }
}]);
```

Your tpl.html will be inside `<div ng-view>`, so, you don't need to repeat this code.

Comment: Thanks. I write it for debug my app. Button outside view is update my {{myData}}, but button inside view is only update $scope, but not update {{myData}}

Comment: Probably because, as I said, you are calling MainCtrl twice. Then, you reset your $scope inside <ng-view>. You should call it once, in <body> or in route.